# How to perform matrix transformations?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm pretty sure I'm missing a huge gap on how to apply the transformations. My attempt is all wrong on probably several fronts

**Question:** 
Assume that T is a linear transformation. Find the standard matrix of T.

T: $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ first reflects points through the line $x_2=-x_1$ and then reflects points through the vertical $x_2$-axis.

**Attempt:**

$$e_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\0 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$e_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\1 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$T(e_1) = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\-1 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$T(e_2) = \begin{bmatrix} -1\\0 \end{bmatrix}$$
Then applying the vertical transformation:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\0  & -1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: The $T(e_1),T(e_2)$ and $A$ are inconsistent with each other. $A e_1$ should agree with $T(e_1)$ and similar for $A e_2 $ and $T(e_2)$.

Comment: Also your $T(e_2)$ is incorrect.  For these geometrically defined transformations, it (almost) always helps to draw a picture.

Comment: @Bye_World hadn't noticed he had not transformed the base vectors correctly. So that too, you're right.

Comment: So $T(e_2)$ = [1 \\ 0]? and then A = [0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0] ?

Comment: Yes and yes.$\ $